# convert a linq statement as expression

Tags: .net, linq, lambda, predicate

i am creating a generic method which generates predicate to filter data. this is my startswtih method

```
Expression.Call(member, typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new[] { typeof(string) }), constant);
```

like wise i need a expression to find comma separated string in a list of string. 
my solution is

```
filterValue.Split(",").Any(f => messageValue.Contains(f))
```

i need to convert this as above method to call as expression.please help..

Comment: Just curious - how you will use your generic method?

Answer (score 0):

Please test it yourself but I think this should work. You can probably improve this code too.

```
var filterValue = Expression.Constant("a,b");
var messageValue = Expression.Constant("b");
var separator = Expression.Constant(new char[] { ',' });

var split = typeof(string).GetMethod("Split", new[] { typeof(char[]) });
var contains = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });

var f = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "f");

var lambda = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Call(messageValue, contains, f), f);
var splitted = Expression.Call(filterValue, split, separator);

var expression = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Any", new[] { typeof(string) }, splitted, lambda);
bool result = (bool)Expression.Lambda(expression).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
```